Problems with my external hard drive, the system recognizes it but doesn't open files since I updated to 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
I am new to using Ubuntu OS and I really need help.
I have problems with my external usb hard drive, the system recognizes it but doesn't open files since I updated to 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat) from 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
I had no problems with the usb hard drive with Jammy Jellyfish.
The check external hard drive doesn't show any physical damage on it.
The error message it displays is:
Failed to mount "TOSHIBA USB"
error mounting /dev/sdb1 at/media/HP230/TOSHIBA USB:
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,  
missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

This problem also occurs with other external hard drives in good condition that I have tried to use and are recognized on other PCs and OS, however the pendrives do open correctly.
I used this command in the terminal: sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1. The results of this command are:
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.

I was unable to get the external hard drive to mount via the terminal with the help of an article: https://linovox.com/how-to-fix-failed-to-mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-on-linux/ but it didn't work.
What can I do to fix it or how can I access my files?

I would check /etc/fstab

sudo nano /etc/fstab

Use blkid to grab the UUID of the drive. lsblk is also useful with grabbing name.
My root drive looks like so in fstab

UUID=03af717e-0908-4026-8d62-8e2d1cd5de7f / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1

or particularly ntfs mounts:

UUID=03af717e-0908-4026-8d62-8e2d1cd5de7f /location/of/mount ntfs-3g errors=remount-ro 0 1

parameters can vary widely, please check documentation for such
Drive letters tend to change so instead of

/dev/sdb2..etc

use the direct UUID of the drive or partition.
Sometimes when I update/reinstall my system it will change drive letters. Sometimes just plugging in new drives could cause the new drive to take that letter really.
This only helps so much, even when you reinstall, you could get a completely different UUID for the drive, so be sure they are the same.

I updated to specify format for ntfs. Just forgot to change a variable.
